# Disable minutes dropdown from html input time

Tags: html, time

I have the following time input in my html:

```
<input id="appt-time" type="time" name="appt-time" value="13:30" />
```

I would like to know how to disable the minutes from the input or how to set minutes always to 'xx:00'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After some time I found a solution that worked for me:

html:

```
<input type="time" step="3600">
```

css:

```
  input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
  }

  input[type="time"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
  input[type="time"]::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
  }
```